# Taxes on sale of principal residence in Ontario

Tags: taxes, canada, real-estate, ontario

Is it correct that in Ontario, if you sell the home which is your primary residence, you pay absolutely no taxes at all on the sale?

Are there any terms and conditions to this?

Comment: no **income tax**. There is land transfer tax and stuff like that. But the gain in your house is not income, if it is your principal residence. Americans deduct their mortgage payments and pay tax on the profits when they sell. Canadians do not deduct mortgage payments and do not pay tax on the profits. We di deduct interest paid as part of investing in something that would be taxable profits (eg a loan to buy investment property.) It is actually quite logical,

Answer (score 1):

> When a principal residence is sold, the gain is not taxable if it has
>   been the person's principal residence for the whole time it has been
>   owned.  This is because the principal residence exemption eliminates
>   the capital gain.  In this case, there is no need to report the sale
>   on your tax return.
>
> To designate a property as the principal residence, it does not have
>   to be the place where the taxpayer lives all the time.  The property
>   will qualify as a principal residence if the taxpayer, taxpayer's
>   spouse or common-law partner, or any of the taxpayer's children lived
>   in it at some time during the year.  However, if it is rented out the
>   situation may change.
>
> [...]
>
> A taxpayer and spouse may only designate one principal residence
>   between them for each tax year after 1981.  For years prior to 1982,
>   each individual taxpayer can designate one principal residence, so if
>   a couple has owned both a primary home and a cottage for decades, the
>   principal residence exemption is available for both homes for the
>   years prior to 1982.

source: [taxtips.ca](http://www.taxtips.ca/filing/principalresidence.htm)